# How to make Windows Explorer file properties show exact times?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, timestamp

When I bring up file properties, I don't want my OS to round off values for me.  But to my surprise, I click on a file, open properties, and see:

```
Created:   Today, June 11, 2015, 4 hours ago
Modified:  Today, June 11, 2015, 4 hours ago
Accessed:  Today, June 11, 2015, 4 hours ago
```

How can I change this back to show the time stamp instead of this rounded-off time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Why does Windows Explorer file properties not show exact times?

> When I bring up file properties, I don't want my OS to round off values for me

This behaviour is caused by the having the long data format set to `Day of the Week` instead of `Day`.

---

#### How do I fix this?

> - Go to Control Panel > Region and Language > Additional Settings > Date
> - Change the “Long date” format to “ddd, MMMM dd, yyyy” (remove one of the ‘d’).
>
> This will change it from the "Long Day" format to the "Abbreviated
> date" format (ie "Thursday" becomes "Thu").
>
> Apparently the "Long date" (my terminology) also understands something
> about "Today", but the "Abbreviated date" (again, my terminology)
> doesn’t, so instead of "Today" it says "Thu".
>
> Because it doesn't know it is "Today", it lists the full time.

Source [Windows 7 Annoyance: File Properties](http://www.nicholasoverstreet.com/2010/03/windows-7-annoyance-file-properties/)

---

#### Further reading

- [Change the display of dates, times, currency, and measurements](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows/change-dates-times-currency-measurements-display#1TC=windows-7)